# how can i create visual studio solution file from nested Qt project using qmake

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt, qmake

when i have nested Qt project with many *.pro files under the root project
i run script ( perl script ) that run recursively with the command

qmake -tp vc *.pro

but is there better way to do it just with qmake alone without scripts ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am sure

```
qmake -r -tp vc mainprojectfile.pro
```

should do the trick. See the [great and extensive documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtdoc/qmake-platform-notes.html#creating-visual-studio-project-files). It's all there.